# AJAX with json call to an ArcGIS service not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, arcgis

I`m trying to update some data in a rest service via a rest call.
For some reason my code isn't working, the code i use is:

```
  var jsonTemp = [{
    attributes : {
      'objectId' : str.objectid,
      'relcp86d_' : str.relcp86d_,
      'relcp86d_i' : str.relcp86d_i,
      'symbol' : str.symbol,
      'polygonid' : str.polygonid,
      'scale' : str.scale,
      'angle' : str.angle,
      'omschrijvi' : str.omschrijvi
    },
    geometry : {
      'x' : str.geometry.flatCoordinates[0],
      'y' : str.geometry.flatCoordinates[1]
    }
  }];

  jsonTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonTemp));
  console.log('jsonTemp: ', jsonTemp);


  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsonTemp,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success ', data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
      alert(xhr.status);
      alert(thrownError);
    }
  });
```

Then if i check the response it looks like some kind of object is in the error code so i don't know what to do.
The error looks like this:

```
Error  Object { readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: [9]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: [9]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: [9]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: [9]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: [9]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.statusCode(), abort: [9]</</<.ajax/jqXHR.abort(), state: [9]</</<.Deferred/promise.state(), always: [9]</</<.Deferred/promise.always(), catch: [9]</</<.Deferred/promise.catch(), 9 meer… }
```

--edit

I was trying to do this via OpenLayers3 first but that didn't work so that's why i try it via this way now.
This is the error code i get using thrownError

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: Wha't the API URL you are using?

Comment: It's a local server i try to update features, which i could show but you wont be able to connect: localhosturl/arcgis/rest/services/test/Gelderland/FeatureServer/0/updateFeatures not sure where a version is you could view

Comment: What does your :  "console.log('jsonTemp: ', jsonTemp);"  command output?

Comment: The output is as suspected, object with attributions and geometry values

Comment: Yes, but maybe one of your values is in incorrect format or has invalid values which causes the error you are getting

Comment: Yes, i understand what you are trying to say this is the result in an image [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0nmsxuw9vyihrq4/object.PNG?dl=0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133275/discussion-between-mike-n88-and-shai-aharoni).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: jsonTemp,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success ', data);
    },
    error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, msg){
      console.log('Error ', textStatus);
    }
  });
```

Comment: I actually just tried it in a similar way and i get this as result:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

So it looks like it doesnt like json at all